# How do I store data in an object rather than a class

Tags: java, android, oop, android-studio

I am trying to create a messaging app with several different xml views/classes:

one for the main menu (**MainActivity**);

one for the sending message screen (**SendMsg**);

one for storing sent messages (**Logs**).

In **SendMsg**, I want to store my message into an object called *msgLog*, which I had created in **MainActivity**.  Just for testing, I have set **SendMsg** to display the **Logs** class upon pressing the *SEND* button, and the sent message does indeed appear there.

However, it is not storing it into the *msgLog* variable that I created, so that I can't access again from **MainActivity**.

How do I store it into a variable, so that it will always be there when I access it?  Any help would be much appreciated.

=========================================================

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Logs msgLog = new Logs();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendOnClick (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.android.attone.SendMsg");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void logsOnClick (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Logs.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

=========================================================

```
public class SendMsg extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;
    Button btnSend;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_msg);

        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
        txtMessage = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        btnSend = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                // Get phone number and message sms
                String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

                Intent writeLog = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Logs.class);
                writeLog.putExtra("link", message);
                startActivity(writeLog);

                // If phone number and message is not empty
                if (phoneNo.length() > 0 && message.length() > 0)
                {
                    sendMessage(phoneNo, message);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enter both number and message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Function send message sms
    private void sendMessage(String phoneNo, String message)
    {
        try
        {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS failed. Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

=========================================================

```
public class Logs extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_logs);

        String logging = getIntent().getStringExtra("link");
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLog);
        textView.setText(logging);

        Button log2menu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.logToMenu);
        log2menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `Logs msgLog = new Logs();` don't do this. **never** instantiate an activity yourself

Comment: *How do I store it into a variable, so that it will always be there when I access it?* if "always" is important, you are gonna have to use a database. Data stored in an object will at most be available until you close the app, then it will be gone

Comment: I see - thanks so much!  I'm quite new to app development, so my knowledge is still very limited, and that wasn't obvious to me.  I'll give it a go now:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences to store such data.
One more thing you can try if you don't want to save the data after the app closes is storing the data in a static variable of a separate class.